# set object field via string

Tags: vb.net, class, object, properties, enumerable

Edit: Total re-edit to illustrate problem more clearly:

Didn't think this would work when I did it:

```
   Dim Label1 As Label
    Dim testvar As String = "BottomRight"
    Dim testalign As ContentAlignment
    testalign = ContentAlignment.testvar
    Label1.TextAlign = testalign
```

"BottomRight" is one of the enumerable choices you get in intellisense. Using a string because full code sets 'Label1.textalign' to different setups depending on a string variable.

Clearly the ContentAlignment.testvar throws an error. I need to preserve the enumerable being set by a string value. Can't get my head around this at all - concepts too advance for my stage, but is there any way to achieve this? Two days searching and loosing hope..

Comment: Why use a string when you already have an enum ?   `testvar = ContentAlignment.BottomRight  :  testalign = testvar`

Comment: As in post - I need to use a string - full code involves string being pulled from dataset and text alignments on individual controls being set from these strings. Thus, as stated above, need to achieve this via strings. But thank you for the answer and apologies if my terminology is wrong/misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally! With Sam's steer, here's how:

```
    Dim Label1 As Label
    Dim testvar As String = "BottomRight"
    Dim testalign As New ContentAlignment
    testalign = CType([Enum].Parse(GetType(ContentAlignment), testvar), ContentAlignment)
    Label1.TextAlign = testalign
```

Not sure it works for all classes - it doesn't with `color`. The enumerated values under `ContentAlignment` are listed as Public Constants - so they may have to be of this type.

Comment: Correct.  This **only** works with Enums.  `Color` is a structure.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use a string variable you have two options:

**option one**

[`Enum.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

**option two**

[`Select Case`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx)

```
Select Case testvar.Trim.ToLower
    Case "bottomright"
        testalign = ContentAlignment.BottomRight

    Case ....
End Select
```

Comment: Thanks Sam. Was trying to avoid the Select Case method as some parts of final code have long lists of enum fields. Read a bit on enum.parse - do you have an example how that would be used in question scenario?

Comment: It's a single method on a class.  I'm sure you can figure out how to use it.